# Filter pandas DataFrame by column time value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a 'date' column, which uses this format:

```
2015-01-01 04:00:00
2015-01-01 05:00:00
2015-01-01 06:00:00
2015-01-01 07:00:00
...
2015-01-02 04:00:00
2015-01-02 05:00:00
2015-01-02 06:00:00
2015-01-02 07:00:00
```

I want to filter the DataFrame so I only keep the rows with a stated time, e.g. 06:00:00

```
2015-01-01 06:00:00
2015-01-02 06:00:00
```

I tried things like

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df[df['date'].time() == datetime.time(6)]
```

But they don't work.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) attribute accessor to access the `hour` attribute to filter the df once the dtype is a datetime:

```
In [141]:
t="""2015-01-01 04:00:00
2015-01-01 05:00:00
2015-01-01 06:00:00
2015-01-01 07:00:00
2015-01-02 04:00:00
2015-01-02 05:00:00
2015-01-02 06:00:00
2015-01-02 07:00:00"""
s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0], header=None, names=['date'])
s[s['date'].dt.hour == 6]

Out[141]:
                 date
2 2015-01-01 06:00:00
6 2015-01-02 06:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a good book about pandas to recommend?

Comment: There is the [original](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) book but its a little out of date, your best bet is here on SO and the online [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)